# Python, считывание из файла

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть файл `input.txt`. В первой строке - число n, количество координат точек декартовой системы. Нужно считать это число `n`, а после значения первого столбца записать в массив `x`, а значения второго столбца - в `y`. Ниже пример файла `input.txt`

```
5
1380 939
2848 96
3510 1671
457 334
3888 666
```

Comment: Так вы приведите свой код и напишите, что конкретно у вас не получается.

Comment: я не пишу на python, поэтому и примерно не знаю, как это реализовать

Comment: В таком случае, вам пора начать писать на python, потому что иначе это выглядит как задание участникам сообщества. А задания здесь не выполняют.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
     ftext = f.read()
x, y = [],[]
z = ftext.split('\n')
for i in range(1,int(z[0])+1):
     x.append(int(z[i].split(' ')[0]))
     y.append(int(z[i].split(' ')[1]))
```

Comment: Возможно не лучшее решение, но должно работать

Comment: получилось, большое спасибо!